# How to estimate GPU FLOPs from porting FPGA Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, gpu, fpga

I've got a series of signal processing algorithms that are currently implemented within an FPGA architecture.  I'd like to move this processing over to a GPU-based server, but I need to come up with an estimate of how many GPUs will be needed.  What is the best way to go about this task?  Should I attempt to breakdown each mathematical operation into a FLOP count and then add it all up and hope that I'm remotely in the ballpark?

Answer (score 0):

If you divide operations required by FLOP count by GPU performance you will get a lower bound for the time required, even in the best possible case, but there is no guarantee that the GPU will actually be able to sustain the performance required for this, or that you will be able to write the programs required for this in any reasonable time. I would also look at what signal processing libraries are available for your chosen GPU, and see if any of them provide something close to what you need. If you could work out that you can do what you need with library calls and some cpu-based glue code, you could time the glue code without a GPU and then look at the library specs to work out how long they would take and come up with a time estimate that you could hope to achieve without too much optimism.